# How to connect to Teradata with C++ on linux

Tags: c++, database-connection, teradata

Simple Problem:
I want to connect my linux based C++ program to a Teradata database.
How do I accomplish this?

I searched the web but I only found some ADO and ODBC based solutions for .net or JDBC drivers. Is there any lib out there that can do the job on linux without ODBC and .net?

Greetings,
Lars

Comment: When you contacted teradata directly, what did they say?  If you have a Teradata database, you should have licenses for their SQL tools.

Comment: I already thought about this. But that would lead to large amounts of paper work on my side... :-/ Stackoverflow is quicker :-)

Comment: @Lars: "large amounts of paper work"?  You already have a license.  You are paying for it.  You should consider the possibility that using it is actually cheaper than hacking around.

Comment: I don't own a license. A big corporation does. Big corporation eq large amount of paper work. :-) I think you get the idea.

Comment: But basically you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Lars: "I think you get the idea".  Not really.  If you don't have a license, how do you think you're going to get access to a Teradata database?  If you're working for a big corporation, they should provide the tools you need to access their database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Teradata Call-Level Interface Version 2 Reference for Network Attached Systems](http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=101320014) - Documentation

[Teradata Developer Exchange - Downloads](http://developer.teradata.com/download) - You can download the CLI for Linux, Windows, Solaris, HP-UX, and AIX from there. You can also find links to other developer resources to download as well. Including VMware images of Teradata and Teradata Express for Windows.

[Teradata Developer Exchange - Forums (Connectivity)](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/connectivity) - Targeted audience to help answer your specific questions working with the CLI interface.

Hope this helps with your research.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Teradata CLI (call level interface). But first, you should contact the teradata customer support and ask for the teradata tools and utilities package and documentation.

Comment: Wow... so CLI is not .net's Common Language Infrastructure but it's Call Level Interface... Great. I love acronyms.. THX!