# Implement a Teradata connector

Tags: c++, teradata, connector

I'm looking for examples that explain how to write a Teradata connector in C++. I'm currently reading the Teradata documentation but it's not very helpful since not chunks of code are shown... Would you have any articles about that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to Teradata with C++ on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551118/how-to-connect-to-teradata-with-c-on-linux)

Comment: I've seen this topic. It didn't really help me except downloading the CLI. I don't find the rest very useful, it doesn't tell me what to do with it. I searched a bit in the Teradata forum but didn't find anything.